# Evaluation of one input in a function with multiple inputs in R

Tags: r, function, derivative

I am trying to do the following but can't figure it out. Could someone please help me?

```
f <- expression(x^3+4*y)
df <- D(f,'x')

x <-0
df0 <- eval(df)
```

df0 should be a function of y!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the derivative of `f` with respect to `x` you get `3 * x^2`. The `4*y` is a constant as far as `x` is concerned. So you don't have a function of `y` as such, your `df` is a constant as far as `y` is concerned (although it is a function of `x`).

Assigning to `x` doesn't change `df`; it remains the expression `3 * x^2` and is still a function of `x` if you wanted to treat it as such.

If you want to substitute a variable in an expression, then `substitute()` is what you are looking for.

```r
> substitute(3 * x^2, list(x = 0))
3 * 0^2
```

It is a blind substitute with no simplification of the expression--we probably expected zero here, but we get zero times 3--but that is what you get.

Unfortunately, substituting in an expression you have in a variable is a bit cumbersome, since `substitute()` thinks its first argument *is* the verbatim expression, so you get

```r
> substitute(df, list(x = 0))
df
```

The expression is `df`, there is no `x` in that so nothing is substituted, and you just get `df` back.

You can get around that with two substitutions and an eval:

```r
> df0 <- eval(
+   substitute(substitute(expr, list(x = 0)), 
+             list(expr = df)))
> df0
3 * 0^2
> eval(df0)
[1] 0
```

The outermost `substitute()` puts the value of `df` into `expr`, so you get the right expression there, and the inner `substitute()` changes the value of `x`.

There are nicer functions for manipulating expressions in the Tidyverse, but I don't remember them off the top of my head.